Prisma ConversionError Unable to fit integer value '6484250528' into an INT4
I am trying to use prisma and postgresql to do a simple query, but the findUnique function throws the below error:
Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error { kind: ToSql(0), cause: Some(Error { kind: ConversionError("Unable to fit integer value '6484250528' into an INT4 (32-bit signed integer)."), original_code: None, original_message: None }) }), transient: false })
    at In.handleRequestError (/Users/yonghe/Desktop/Projects/Tradex Bot/tradex-bot/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7067)
    at In.handleAndLogRequestError (/Users/yonghe/Desktop/Projects/Tradex Bot/tradex-bot/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:6211)
    at In.request (/Users/yonghe/Desktop/Projects/Tradex Bot/tradex-bot/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:5919)
    at async l (/Users/yonghe/Desktop/Projects/Tradex Bot/tradex-bot/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:127:11167) {
  clientVersion: '5.15.1'
}

schema.prisma
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id             Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId         Int     @unique
  chatId         Int
}

const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { userId: 6484250528} })


That's correct, that won't fit. Use a bigint.

Will bigint slow down the SQL query? or should I use String instead of Int?

The answer is Yes. But if you will notice this slow down, is a very different question. That answer will most likely be No. When it comes to performance, your ORM is much bigger challenge than a BIGINT.
